# Issue non-deletable vertices in edit mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

[image]

I don't know why, but when I try to delete a certain area of the building in *Edit Mode*, those thin lines will be made up and even show up in *Render Mode* and cannot be selected.

Does anybody know why is this occurring, and how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to BlenderStackExchange. Without a blend file, we can only guess at what your problem's issue could be.

Comment: Oh okay, i'll post blender file too

Comment: @krvkn: it is always a good info if you write, whether you are total beginner or if you have some experience. Because the details of the answers will be very low if they think you know Blender.

Comment: Oof okay, Looks like I was just not knowing about blender at all:) Thanks for answers and I'll try to learn blender more

Comment: @krvkn: if my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. press TAB to go to edit mode
2. select "Vertex select" mode

[image]

3. select vertex

[image]

4. press X and choose vertices

[image]

result:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

those vertices where deleted for me btw , just press "tab" key on your keyboard and select vets by mouse and press "x" on your keyboard again and click on delete vertices

but its best to use boolean in these situations
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126317/discussion-on-answer-by-hamed-design-issue-re-non-deletable-vertices-in-edit-mod).